# How to disable the "restore tabs" popup in chrome when it is killed abruptly?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to know how to disable the "Restore Tabs Popup"  which appears when Google Chrome is opened after being ended abruptly?

This is creating an issue in my Automation Process. I want to run specific chrome Profiles and change the chrome Profiles each hour automatically . I have created scripts and automated opening and closing of Chrome profiles using task scheduler. But this popup is becoming big Hurdle for me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8M9w.jpg)!

Each time It needs to be cancelled manually! Any solution please?

I have shown screenshot here.

I have tried ways that were available on Google. Like finding "Exit_type" in preferences file in Chrome folder or going to Chrome Flags in experiment section of Chrome but this doesn't helped!

Comment: this question has been answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/237608/how-to-hide-chrome-warning-after-crash